# What does ' > ' means in scipy.sparse for the operation on coo_matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, adjacency-matrix

I am struggling with the ' > ' in the scipy.sparse coo_matrix.

`adj = sp.coo_matrix((np.ones(edges.shape[0]), (edges[:, 0], edges[:, 1])), shape=(labels.shape[0], labels.shape[0]), dtype=np.float32)`

````
# build symmetric adjacency matrix
```adj = adj + adj.T.multiply(adj.T > adj) - adj.multiply(adj.T > adj)```

As what you see, there is a ` > `. I hope to know what it means.
````

Comment: What's the source of this code?

Comment: See https://github.com/Diego999/pyGAT/blob/master/utils.py line 29. Ta